# Querystring from AngularJS not showing up in classic ASP

Tags: angularjs, asp-classic

I'm trying to make an ajax call from Angular to classic ASP, to retrieve some data from my db. However in ASP I cannot find the querystring; when I response.write(request.querystring) or request.form nothing shows up, and I am unable to query for individual form variables.

The Angular call is like this:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('myajaxpage.asp',{'Term':'hello','Username':'world'})
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}, function(response) {
    console.log('FAILURE');
});
});
```

I'm very new to Angular so don't even really understand how it submits this (is it technically a querystring or a form?) let alone how to retrieve it in ASP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the $http.get() to access the ASP page, send the parameters in the URL as: page.asp?x=1 (request this data using request.querystring). If you use the $http.post, I belive that you can request the data using request.form.